# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response head already sent Vert.x

Tags: java, authentication, vert.x, mutiny

I'm working on a Vert.x project using Mutiny APIs for asynchronous operations. I want to authenticate a user and also secure the endpoints, I created a CustomAuthicationProvider from Vert.x AuthCommon, it takes in a phone number and password as credentials. when I test the endpoint it throws the exception

> [ntloop-thread-1] c.a.a.h.CustomAuthenticationProvider     : User Logged in
> 2023-10-04T16:15:35.936+01:00  INFO 9919 --- [ntloop-thread-1] c.a.a.controller.LoginController         : User Logged intrue
> [-- Mutiny had to drop the following exception --]
> Exception received by: io.smallrye.mutiny.infrastructure.Infrastructure.handleDroppedException(Infrastructure.java:295)
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response head already sent
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.checkHeadWritten(Http1xServerResponse.java:709)
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.setStatusCode(Http1xServerResponse.java:149)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.checkHandleNoMatch(RoutingContextImpl.java:156)
> at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:142)

But from the logs, the user is logged in. Below is my code

CustomAuthenticationProvider

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);
    private final PgPool pgPool;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider(PgPool pgPool) {
        this.pgPool = pgPool;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(JsonObject jsonObject, Handler<AsyncResult<User>> handler) {

        String phoneNumber = jsonObject.getString("phoneNumber");
        String password = jsonObject.getString("password");

        pgPool.withConnection(conn ->
                conn.prepare("SELECT p.phoneNumber, p.password FROM Users p WHERE p.phoneNumber = $1 AND p.password = $2")
                        .flatMap(preparedStatement ->
                                preparedStatement.query().execute(Tuple.of(phoneNumber, password))
                        )
                        .map(rowSet -> {
                            if (rowSet.rowCount() == 1) {
                                return rowSet.iterator().next();
                            }
                            return null;
                        })
        )
                .subscribe()
                .with(
                row -> {
                    if (row != null) {
                        User user = new UserImpl();

                        LOGGER.info("User Logged in");
                        handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(user));
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("Invalid credentials");
                        handler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Invalid credentials"));
                    }
                },
                error -> {
                    LOGGER.error("Authentication failed with error: " + error.getMessage());
                    handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(error.getMessage()));
                }
        );
    }
}
```

LoginController

```
public class LoginController implements Function<RoutingContext, Uni<Void>> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);
    private static final String CONTENT = "content-type";
    private static final String JSON_TYPE = "application/json";
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(Router router, CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
        router.post("/login")
                .handler(BodyHandler.create())
                .respond(this);


    }

    @Override
    public Uni<Void> apply(RoutingContext ctx) {
        JsonObject credentials = JsonObject.mapFrom(ctx.body().asPojo(LoginData.class));


        customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(credentials, res -> {

            if (res.succeeded()) {

                LOGGER.info("User Logged in" + res.succeeded());
                ctx.getDelegate().next();
                ctx.getDelegate().response()
                        .setStatusCode(200)
                        .putHeader(CONTENT, JSON_TYPE)
                        .end(new JsonObject().put("Success", "Login in successful").encode());


            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Authentication failed with error" + res.cause().getMessage());
                ctx.getDelegate().response()
                        .setStatusCode(401)
                        .putHeader(CONTENT, JSON_TYPE)
                        .end(new JsonObject().put("error", "Authentication failed").encodePrettily());

            }
        });

        return Uni.createFrom().nullItem();
    }
}
```

When I remove ctx.response() and ctx.next() from the code it runs smoothly and the logs display logged in but Postman returns 204 no response. when I tried to use the return statement for ctx.response() the method succeeded() cannot be resolved. What is the best way to implement this? I want a simple way to implement this and not with the JWT Auth provider because I'm not using JWT for this project.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vert.x so I can't tell where the error is exactly, but I can tell you what the problem is: You are modifying some aspect of the response (e.g. status code, headers, cookies) *after* you have started sending the body. That's not possible with HTTP, the status and headers *must* be sent first. So the framework is telling you you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks, But I used the same method for other endpoints and it worked